# How to fix selective area of Empty drop-down in Firefox browser through CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I am facing an issue with empty drop-down. When I click on the empty drop-down,
it shows the dotted selective area below. It is only reproducible in Firefox. It is working fine for IE and Chrome. Can anyone suggest how I might handle this?

[image: Screenshot of empty drop down, selected]

```html
<body>
<div>
<select id ="ishan" size="6"  style ="top: 164.167px; left: 237.7px; visibility: visible; z-index: -1; width: 282px;">
 
</select>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Probaly is the Firefox implementation of an empty select tag. But IMHO I dont think should be a problem because a select tag is not supposed to be without any option inside.

Comment: But i didn't see such behavior for IE and Chrome. dotted area doesn't show for IE and Chrome.

Comment: I cant change my implementation,  i need to fix it for firefox. can i handle it through any CSS property ?

Comment: this is a good question. Edit your original question and ask how to hanlde through CSS. It is more specific and is easier you can find an aswer

Comment: ok thanks @dparoli